# Replace default Ruby version in OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, version, rvm, osx-lion

I don't have any 1.8.x Ruby apps to maintain so I was thinking about getting rid of RVM by replacing pre-installed Ruby with the 1.9 version on my OS X Lion.

Is it possible? How do I do it? Should I just delete the current interpreter and replace it with a new one?

Or is there a better way to always have 1.9.2 at hand? All I want is a Lion with 1.9.2 :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is a Lion with Ruby 1.9.2, just install it (either compile it yourself or through  Homebrew) and make sure to add the relevant directories to your PATH before the one's of the system Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to update your ruby on osx, check
`brew info ruby` to have more info on the version installed, etc.

Comment: My solution is out of date, you should probably use rbenv if you want to do this nowadays (April 2014)